# How to insert checked checkboxes values in access database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, checkbox

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jay.desai\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\Test.mdb");

con.Open();   
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into EmpTest values(@Emp_No,@Gender,@Language)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_No", textBox1.Text);
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton1.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton2.Text);
            }
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", checkBox1.Text);
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", checkBox2.Text);
            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", checkBox3.Text);
            }
            if (checkBox4.Checked)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", checkBox4.Text);
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

when i click on submit button only the first checked checkbox value inserted in database??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to write all the languages checked to the database you need to build a string with the cumulative text of the checkbox selected.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jay.desai\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\Test.mdb"))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into EmpTest values(@Emp_No,@Gender,@Language)", con))
{
    con.Open();   
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_No", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GetGender());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", GetLanguages());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

private string GetLanguage()
{
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     if (checkBox1.Checked)
         result.AppendFormat("{0},", checkBox1.Text);
     if (checkBox2.Checked)
         result.AppendFormat("{0},", checkBox2.Text);
     if (checkBox3.Checked)
         result.AppendFormat("{0},", checkBox3.Text);
     if (checkBox4.Checked)
         result.AppendFormat("{0},", checkBox4.Text);
     if(result.Length > 0) result.Lenght--;
     return result.ToString();
}

private string GetGender()
{
    return (radioButton1.Checked ? radioButton1.Text : radioButton2.Text);
}
```

instead, if you need just one Language then you should remove your checkbox controls and use a radiobutton exclusive set of controls like you do for the Gender field

Comment: When you reach the needed reputation (15 I think) I suggest you to upvote also the other answers because we are essentially saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the values to the same DB parameter `@Language`. If you want them all to be added to the database, create separate fields/params for each checkbox.

Also, assuming that you have checked all four checkboxes, i would expect the last checkbox value to be inserted and not the first.

However, by the looks of things you want to concatenate the text values of each checkbox where they are checked?

You could achieve this effect via:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
     sb.Append(checkBox1.Text);
}
if (checkBox2.Checked)
{
     sb.Append(checkBox2.Text);
}
if (checkBox3.Checked)
{
    sb.Append(checkBox3.Text);
}
if (checkBox4.Checked)
{
    sb.Append(checkBox4.Text);
}

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you overwrite earlier values for `@Language` when more than 1 checkbox is checked:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_No", textBox1.Text);
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton1.Text);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton2.Text);
}

string languages = new List<string>();

if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    languages.Add(checkBox1.Text);
}
if (checkBox2.Checked)
{
    languages.Add(checkBox2.Text);
}
if (checkBox3.Checked)
{
    languages.Add(checkBox3.Text);
}
if (checkBox4.Checked)
{
    languages.Add(checkBox4.Text);
}   

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", string.Join(",", languages.ToArray());

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

this will insert all checked languages separated by comma.